# AR.JS New Pattern Each Time Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js, ar.js

I am using the AR.JS generator and I am trying to make a custom pattern every time the page is loaded, usually you have to upload your own centre image but with this I want to make it so it auto generates. I am using an api called qrserver which creates a QR code for you and lets you use that, unfortunately when I use the code below the entire image view does not display. Usually the src takes in a file called "example.png" which is in the file directory.

Any solutions or other ways to do this??

```
THREEx.ArPatternFile.buildFullMarker =  function(innerImageURL, pattRatio, onComplete){
    var whiteMargin = 0.1
    var blackMargin = (1 - 2 * whiteMargin) * ((1-pattRatio)/2)
    // var blackMargin = 0.2

    var innerMargin = whiteMargin + blackMargin

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    canvas.width = canvas.height = 512

    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)

    // copy image on canvas
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillRect(
        whiteMargin * canvas.width,
        whiteMargin * canvas.height,
        canvas.width * (1-2*whiteMargin),
        canvas.height * (1-2*whiteMargin)
    );

    // clear the area for innerImage (in case of transparent image)
    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    context.fillRect(
        innerMargin * canvas.width,
        innerMargin * canvas.height,
        canvas.width * (1-2*innerMargin),
        canvas.height * (1-2*innerMargin)
    );


    // display innerImage in the middle
    var innerImage = document.createElement('img')
    innerImage.addEventListener('load', function(){
        // draw innerImage
        context.drawImage(innerImage,
            innerMargin * canvas.width,
            innerMargin * canvas.height,
            canvas.width * (1-2*innerMargin),
            canvas.height * (1-2*innerMargin)
        );

        var imageUrl = canvas.toDataURL()
        onComplete(imageUrl)
    })
    innerImage.src = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=500x500&data=test'
}
```